Gazebo Migration - Sensor plugins in world
First of all thanks to the Gazebo devs for the Gazebo Migration guide.
Quoting from the guide "As mentioned earlier, sensors are handled by generic world level plugins. [...] Therefore, we have to add the additional plugins for IMU and Lidar sensors as well as the ones that would have been added by default". Does this mean that I cannot reuse the same world file to run simulation of different robots (which have different sensors hence plugins)? In other terms world files are no longer robot-independent?
Thank you in advance to anyone that can clarify this.

One question per post please.
